# How to display image in React-Admin from local folder - path fetched from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-admin

I fetch data from my mongoDB server. Everything displays correctly but the image.

```
<ImageField source='filename' title="image" />
```

filename is, let's say, 'book-2929646_960_720.jpg'. This image is stored in a local folder (not the same one as my react-admin component).

How should I modify the source path for the image to be displayed? I've tried using template literals in order to build the path, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `<ImageField>` - that's a current limitation.

You can use [the `<FunctionField>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#functionfield) for that:

```
const FilenameField = props => <FunctionField 
   {...props}
   render={record => <img src={`/foo/bar/${record.filename}`} title="image" />} 
/>;
```